# Where to put the hibernate configuration file when using Tomcat 7?

Tags: hibernate, tomcat

Where shall I put the configuration file (hibernate.hbm.xml) when I deploy webapps (JSF 2.0) using Tomcat 7.0?

It works when I place it in WEB-INF/classes/ but is that the "standard" path? Where do you place it?

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be in the root of the classpath. If you have two directories in the classpath, hibernate.cfg.xml can be in any of them. For web applications, the root of the classpath is WEB-INF/classes.